# pushwoosh how to use filter with python

Tags: python, filter, pushwoosh

I use pushwoosh for notification for the ios. The notifications works now, but it sends now to all devices. How can I use a filter with python to send only to specific user?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to set the devices parameter in the library you are using. What library are you using?